# Angular routing redirectTo

Tags: angularjs, javascript

Банальный роутинг в ангулар.

```
.config ['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->

    $routeProvider

    ...

    .otherwise
        redirectTo: '/index'
]
```

Но вместо того, чтобы выбрасывало на `localhost/index`, почему-то выбрасывает в `localhost/#/index`, и вообще без понятия, почему добавляется в начале `/#`, кто с такми сталкивался или есть идеи, почему так срабатывает?

Так, например, когда я захожу на `localhost/ok`, то происходит редирект на `localhost/ok#/index`.

Comment: так и должно быть!

Comment: Почему не должно быть редирект на 'http://localhost/index' ?

Comment: Так работает routing любой Javascript framework по умолчанию. Когда добавляется хэш в URL (#), не происходит перезагрузки страницы, в отличие от варианта изменения URI. Вроде как есть возможности сделать и первый вариант без перезагрузки страницы с AngularJS, но никогда не пытался это воспроизвести.

Comment: Смотрите https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location начиная с Hashbang and HTML5 Modes.
Ключевой момент:

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Но не забывайте что это только внешнее изменение пути в строке адреса. Никакой страницы по этому пути не появится и когда пользователь вобьет в строку адреса этот линк он увидит 404. Поэтому вам нужно позаботится чтоб роутинг на фронтенде и на бекенде соответсвовали друг другу и показывали нужную страницу в любом случае.

Comment: @LinnTroll Что-бы пофиксить 404, нужно добавить .htaccess с RewriteRule, и все запросы перенаправлять на /index.html, что бы все корректно работало.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел решение, спасибо LinnTroll за ссылку.

```
app.config ['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
    ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) ->

        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode
                enabled: true
                requireBase: false
            .hashPrefix '!'

        $routeProvider

        ...

        .otherwise
            redirectTo: '/index'
]
```

Теперь все работает как надо. `localhost/asdfjasdlfk;j -> localhost/index`

Comment: @Алексей Данчин [Это называется `pushState`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/). Не поддерживается [IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=pushstate). Вы должны трезво оценивать риски, ибо ещё "вчера" такой возможности не было. Потому в angular данная опция отключена по дефолту.